# Brussel Sprout Random Variable, Mean, SD, and Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

A local farmer's market sells 1 pound bags of Brussels Sprouts. The farmer believes that the mean number of Brussels Sprouts in each bag is 18 with a standard deviation of 3.4. You buy 2 pounds of Brussels Sprouts.

a. You want to explore the range of sizes between brussels sprouts. You find the difference between the number of sprouts in your two bags. Define your random variable for this situation, and find its mean and standard deviation.

**I'm a bit confused with this question. Would the random variable be the # (number) of brussels sprouts in each bag? Wouldn't the mean be 18 and the standard deviation be 3.4?**

b. IF the number of Brussels Sprouts per bag is normally distributed, what is the probability that the difference in number of Brussels Sprouts between two bags is more than 4?

**I have no idea how to answer b. Would we make a normal probability distribution and use normalcdf?**

Answer (score 0):

If $X_i$ is the number of sprouts in bag $i\in\{1,2\}$, then the random variable representing the difference in the number of sprouts in the two bags is $X_1-X_2$. We are given $X_i\sim N(18,3.4^2)$, so$$E[X_1-X_2]=E[X_1]-E[X_2]=0$$and assuming independence$$V[X_1-X_2]=V[X_1]+V[X_2]=3.4^2+3.4^2$$giving $\sigma_{X_1-X_2}=(3.4)\sqrt2$.

For solving $(b)$, use the fact that the [difference of two independent normal random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506758/sum-of-independent-normal-random-variables) $X_{1,2}$ is a normal variable $X$ with expectation $\mu_X=\mu_{X_1}-\mu_{X_2}$ and variance $\sigma_X^2=\sigma_{X_1}^2+\sigma_{X_2}^2$.